# URL Rewrite in IIS7 Web Service - WebService.asmx => WebService in the SOAP doc

Tags: iis-7.5, rewrite, xml, soap, wsdl

I have an IIS7.5 (Server 2008 R2) based web service that I would like to make as independant on the current implementations technology as possible. I am using the URL rewrite module (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/734/url-rewrite-module/) to remove the .asmx portion of the URL and that is working fine for the HTTP request portion. However, I still see .asmx in the WSDL file when I access it. I was wondering if anyone has done this and if so, what advice could be offered.

It doesn't seem like a hard problem to solve. But I have tries a number of things with "custom tags" and can't seem to get it working to save my life.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - URL Rewriting does not see to be able to handle non-html pages. I am not able to get anything other than a 500 server error when the returned body is SOAP xml, regardless of rules or preconditions. In fact, the simplest rule that I can imagine - " .* " fails in the same way.

Comment: Why do the web gods hate us, Jeff?